# Can I prevent an Ack from being sent with the Grails RabbitMQ plugin?

Tags: grails, rabbitmq, grails-plugin, grails-plugin-rabbitmq

The Grails RabbitMQ plugin is great, but I can't seem to find any information about what to do when processing a message fails. I would prefer *not* to send an Ack back to RabbitMQ, but I can't seem to find any information on how to do this using the plugin.

Is it possible to control this with the RabbitMQ plugin for grails, or am I stuck *not using* the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of Grails RabbitMQ plugin (0.3.3) do not support manual acknowledge mode.

Under the hood Grails RabbitMQ plugin use Spring AMQP libraries, so you can always declare your custom `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` in `resources.groovy` and implement a listener with manual acks. Check out http://static.springsource.org/spring-amqp/reference/html/#d0e377

Comment: Could you please provide a suggestion on how this can be done?